# Factorization of conjugacy equation's solutions in Monoids

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, monoid

**01-28 Update:** *In the first version I was claiming that the authors were not  explicitly or implicitly but I was wrong so I change my question [long explaination at the end of the question]*

---

Two elements of a non-commutative Monoid $a,b\in M$ are conjugate if exists an element $\varphi\in M$ such that the *conjugacy equation*  holds

$$\varphi a=b\varphi$$

I will call $\varphi$ "a solution" of the congugacy equation and denote the *set of solutions* with $\mathcal C(a,b)$ since I don't know the common notation.

$$\mathcal C(a,b):=\{\varphi:\varphi a=b\varphi\}$$

*CE:=conjugacy equation*

---

I'm reading a paper on [Meromorphic solution of conjugacy equations](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/%7Eamen/2012/110415-1.pdf) that talks about the connection between $\mathcal C(a,b)$ and $\mathcal C(a,a)$, the solutions of a special case kind of conjugacy equation (where $a=b$) that is called "*permutable functional equation*" (PFE).

The very first lemma they give is the following

> **LEMMA**: let $\varphi_0$ be a particular solution of [*the C.E.*] Then every solution $\varphi$
> of [*C.E.*] is given by
> $$\varphi=\varphi_0\alpha$$
> where  $\alpha$ is a solution* of [*PFE*].

(*)It assumes that $\alpha\in \mathcal C(a,a)$
And then they prove it as follows

> **PROOF**: since $\varphi$ is a solution of [*CE*], we have $\varphi_0 a=b\varphi_0$. For any solution $\alpha$ of [*PFE*], let $\varphi=\varphi_0\alpha$  , then
>
> $$\varphi a=(\varphi_0\alpha) a=\varphi_0a\alpha=b(\varphi_0\alpha)=b\varphi$$
> This completes the proof.

I can't understand how this proof is enough to prove the lemma. It seems that everything it does is to prove that

> if $\varphi_0\in \mathcal C(a,b)$ and $\alpha \in \mathcal C(a,a)$ then $\varphi_0\alpha \in\mathcal C(a,b)$

In other words $\mathcal C(a,b)$ is closed under right multiplication by elements of $\mathcal C(a,a)$: $\forall\varphi_0\in\mathcal C(a,b) $

> $$\varphi_0\mathcal C(a,a)\subseteq \mathcal C(a,b)$$

but the lemma seems to claim something stronger (in my opinion): fixed a $\varphi_0\in \mathcal C(a,b)$

> For all $\varphi \in \mathcal C(a,b)$ exists an $\alpha \in C(a,a)$ such that $\varphi=\varphi_0\alpha$

that to me seems more like claiming that $\varphi_0\mathcal C(a,a)= \mathcal C(a,b)$ for every $\varphi_0$.

If $M$ is a group then $\alpha$ is given by $\varphi_0'\varphi$ that in fact satisfies the PFE of $\alpha$

$\varphi_0'\varphi a=\varphi_0' b\varphi=a\varphi_0'\varphi$ thus $\varphi_0'\varphi\in \mathcal C (a,a)$

So $\varphi\mapsto \varphi_0'\varphi$ defines a bijection $\mathcal C (a,b)\rightarrow \mathcal C (a,a)$ <strike>but the paper doesn't assumes invertibility since it is talking about composition of functions</strike>(**) and in the proof uses only the associativity axiom.

I feel like I'm missing something, if it is too trivial I'd like hints too.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

---

(**) Note about the paper: The Lemma 1 (pag 2 of the link) says that $\varphi_0$ is a solution of the CE (referred as Eq. (1) in the paper) but the authors seems to cosider only the homeomorphic solutions $\varphi$ of the equation $\varphi\circ f=g\circ\varphi$ thus $\varphi_0$ is invertible and should complete the proof.

Comment: Why is $\phi_{0}' b \phi = a \phi_{0}' \phi$ in the group case?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I guess that we have to prove that $\phi_0\in\mathcal C(a,b)$ implies $\phi_0'\in\mathcal C(b,a)$ in groups. $\phi_0 a=b\phi_0$ (by def.) 
$$\phi_0 a\phi_0'=b\phi_0\phi_0'=b$$
$$\phi_0'\phi_0 a\phi_0'=a\phi_0'=\phi_0'b$$

Comment: Could you give the references of this paper?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I will add the link in the question, anyways even if in the lemma they don't state it explicit they are referring to homeomorphic solutions of the conjugacy equation so they are assuming invertible solutions.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Added the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read the reference paper and you forgot an important hypothesis. In the paper, $\varphi$ denotes an homeomorphism, which means in terms of monoids, that
$\varphi$ and $\varphi_0$ are inversible.

The conclusion is now easy. Suppose that $\varphi$ and $\varphi_0$ are in $C(a,b)$ and let $\alpha = \varphi_0^{-1}\varphi$. Then $\varphi = \varphi_0\alpha$
$\varphi a = b\varphi$ and $\varphi_0 a = b\varphi_0$. It follows that $\varphi_0\alpha a = b \varphi_0\alpha = \varphi_0 a\alpha$ and finally
$\varphi_0^{-1}\varphi_0\alpha a = \varphi_0^{-1}\varphi_0 a\alpha$, that is $\alpha a = a \alpha$. Thus $\alpha \in C(a,a)$.

Comment: 7hours ago I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: OK. Then you should probably delete your question since it becomes trivial.

Comment: It is not that trivial to me: so you say that the lemma, as stated in the question (without the invertibility of $\varphi_0$), is not prooved by that proof? I still wonder if is still possible to find a correct proof. A weak requirement for the general proof  is the existence of at least an invertible element in every $\mathcal C(a,b)$ set... I wonder if this is the weakest requirement, 
In other word I'm gonna rework the question better.